# how can i do redirection with htaccess for my https url

Tags: .htaccess

i need to redirect my old url on the new one 
i try :

RewriteEngine On
redirect    301 https://www.my old******    https://www.my new****

it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to redirect all request to the new domains home:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* https://www.mynew.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work , i have a list of Urls and i must change every old url with a new one